# Cartthrob fails to load custom extension

Tags: cartthrob

I have working production with Cartthrob v. 2.0373

After upgrading EE to 2.8.1 and CT to 2.5 - when I try to add something in my cart - through the URL (http://staging.heartfoundation.org.nz/shop/product_view/12235/good-food-cook-book) I'm getting this error during the custom extension, which can't be found.

---

A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined index: hf_cartthrob

Filename: libraries/Extensions.php

Line Number: 193

---

The interesting this is however that i have database previously upgraded and to ee 281 and cart throb with this later version and this problem does not occurring.

I found the file ext.hf_cartthrob.php in system_213_working/system/e..e../extensions and I copied it to my system/ee/extensions
but nothing changed.

My question is: where the custom extensions are located in new version, or probably there is some setting in the database that preventing this error, when I try to switch the database to stage version, where I originally did the EE update?

Comment: Hi Vladyn, Cartthrob isn't tested and ready for EE 2.8 yet and as such isn't being supported on EE 2.8 yet. Can you go down to EE 2.7.3?

Comment: I'm not sure this is the problem here. As I mentioned I have two databases that I'm switching over and files + add-ons updated. EE is 2.8.1 and by switching the DB 1 I don;t have this problem.